# How to set forign key in relational database with one entity table and many relationship tables? (django)

Tags: django-models, foreign-keys

I am developing an app in Django.

My apps takes in input some information from excel sheets, elaborates them through dataframes, and then generates tables (dataframes) of the relational model I want to build. The data inside these dataframes is then saved inside django models.

However, I don’t know how to write the Django models in order to set the foreign keys properly.

In the relational model that I designed, there is just one entity table and many relationship tables.

Here is what I would like to represent:

[image]

Here are the tables that I prepared with my script (dataframes):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(If I copy paste there tables in Microsoft Access and link them through queries, it returns the desired results – I tryed).

Here are the models I prepared:

```
class Things(models.Model): 
    ID = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    Thing = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Has_other_form(models.Model): 
    ID_soggetto = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ID_oggetto = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Has_definition (models.Model): 
    ID_soggetto = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ID_oggetto = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Has_source (models.Model): 
    ID_soggetto = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ID_oggetto = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

However, I don’t know which fields set as ForeignKey and how to set the parameters.

I have tried:

```
class Things(models.Model): 
    ID = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    Thing = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Has_other_form(models.Model): 
    ID_soggetto = models.ForeignKey('Things', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ID_oggetto = models.ForeignKey('Things', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Has_definition (models.Model): 
    ID_soggetto = models.ForeignKey('Things', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ID_oggetto = models.ForeignKey('Things', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Has_source (models.Model): 
    ID_soggetto = models.ForeignKey('Things', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ID_oggetto = models.ForeignKey('Things', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

but it returns these errors:

> Reverse accessor for 'Has_source.ID_object' clashes with reverse
>   accessor for 'Has_source.ID_subject'.
>
> Reverse accessor for 'Has_definition.ID_object' clashes with reverse
>   accessor for 'Has_definition.ID_subject'.
>
> Reverse accessor for 'Has_other_form.ID_object' clashes with reverse
>   accessor for 'Has_other_form.ID_subject'.

This makes me think that Django cannot handle a model where the same entity table is target of two foreign keys of the same relational table.

Am I right? How can I use Django models to represent my relational schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it, by changing the models so:

```
class Things(models.Model): 
    ID_subject = models.ForeignKey('Things', related_name='%(class)s_as_subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ID_object = models.ForeignKey('Things', related_name='%(class)s_as_object', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Has_other_form(models.Model): 
    ID_subject = models.ForeignKey('Things', related_name='%(class)s_as_subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ID_object = models.ForeignKey('Things', related_name='%(class)s_as_object', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Has_definition (models.Model): 
    ID_subject = models.ForeignKey('Things', related_name='%(class)s_as_subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ID_object = models.ForeignKey('Things', related_name='%(class)s_as_object', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Has_source (models.Model): 
    ID_subject = models.ForeignKey('Things', related_name='%(class)s_as_subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ID_object = models.ForeignKey('Things', related_name='%(class)s_as_object', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```